# Enter data in html textbox and show it in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created two tables: Artist and Song. Artist table has fields Artistid and ArtistName and Song table has SongID, Lyrics, Description and Artistid as the secondary key. I have a web form to add new artist containing a textbox and submit button.

The code is as below :

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method ="post"> 
        <div style="width: 960px; color: black; border: 2px solid black;                 text-align:"center">
            <table>
                <tr> 
                    <td> <label>Artist: </label>
                        <input type="text" name ="textArtist" id ="txtartist"  value = "" /> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <p align="center" > 
                            <input type = "button" id= "btnArtist" value ="submit" /> 
                        </p> 
                    </td> 
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

My requirement is that I will enter some name in textbox and click on submit , the same name should be shown in artist table in the database . 
I have also created a namespace using Mygenerations with the artist and song table . I have written the foll code but it does not show the data in database .it does not work properly . Please help. 
 The code behind file is as below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using NCI.EasyObjects ;
using TestSong ;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strcon = "Company";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void btnartist_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s_artistname = textArtist.Value; 
        Artist oArtist = new Artist(strcon);
        oArtist.Where.ArtistName.Value = s_artistname;
        if (!oArtist.Query.Load())
        {
            oArtist.AddNew();
            oArtist.ArtistName = textArtist.Value;
            oArtist.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Also I am getting an error for the line that has `textArtist.Value`. The error is `textArtist` does not exist in current context. Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Can be more reasons but for now you have used txtArtist as the Id. So use this

```
  string s_artistname = txtArtist.Value;
```

and

```
  oArtist.ArtistName = txtArtist.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `runat=server` if you want to access it in code-behind

```
<input type="text" name ="textArtist" id ="txtartist"  runat="server" />
```

Comment: I have tried the above ..the error is gone but m not getting the data displayed in the database  .

Comment: Hi i got the above working , Now d next thing is I have created a web form that a textbox for song description , dropdownlist for artist name , textarea for the lyrics and a submit button. What I need is that I will enter a song name , select that particular artist for the song and enter lyrics and all these changes should be reflected in database .

Comment: protected void btnSubmitSong_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ Songs oSong = new Songs(strcon); 
  oSong.Where.Description.Value = txtDescription.Value;
  if (!oSong.Query.Load())
  {
   oSong.AddNew();
   oSong.s_Description = txtDescription.Value;
   oSong.Save();}  AddLyrics();  }
 private void BindArtistData()
{
 Artist oArtist = new Artist(strcon);
if(oArtist.Query.Load()) {
 ddlArtist.DataTextField = "ArtistName";
 ddlArtist.DataValueField = "ArtistID";
 ddlArtist.DataSource = oArtist.DefaultView.Table;
 ddlArtist.DataBind();
  ddlArtist.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }    }

Comment: N i able to get the song name , lyrics in the database as well but not at the same time . suppose if i enter song name and its lyrics it will show only lyrics and not song name in database . somebody please help.i need to solve it by today .